# How to integrate multiple shiny apps into one single shiny web application?

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to integrate multiple shiny app into a single shiny application but it is showing errors or crashing. I know that r shiny is single threaded, it can't handle multiple threads. But can't i give runApp("otherapplication") in a shiny app. Are there any methods to integrate multiple apps?

Comment: You can create multiple `shiny` apps each with separate R process. Then use `iframe` to get them together into one application

Comment: Or you can try to use shiny modules http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: @PorkChop maybe post as an answer with an example?

Comment: @Batanichek maybe post as an answer with an example?