# Switch between two shiny apps in one

Tags: r, shiny

So I have two standalone onefile `shinyApps`, with the UI and the Server, inside a function.

Now what I need to do is to call the second app in the first one.

This is a simple example (the functions are simplified to show the functionality that I want to implement):

```
appOne <- function() {
  app <- list(ui = NULL, server = NULL)
  app$ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
    column(3),
    mainPanel(h2("Welcome to the load page"),actionButton("browse", strong("Browse Variants"), class = "btn-success")))
  )
  app$server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$browse, {
      appTwo()
    })
  }
  runApp(app)
}

appTwo <- function() {
  app <- list(ui = NULL, server = NULL)
  app$ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
    column(3),
    mainPanel(h2("Welcome to appTwo"), plotOutput("plot")))
  )
  app$server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(cars)
    })
  }
  runApp(app)
}
```

So what I need is to switch to the second app when the users clicks the button in the first one. Any ideas?

Comment: Relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960829/how-to-integrate-multiple-shiny-apps-into-one-single-shiny-web-application

Comment: @zx8754 Similar, but the question is not answered.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. Here is my solution. It needs to be tested with larger and independant applications, but it sounds answering your question.

I added a selector application (called appRoute, but in fact the routing function is ensured by the infinite loop). Each application needs to have a quit button. Applications communicate by the means of their return/stop code (shiny stopApp function). The shiny print function is calling shiny runApp function.

It should be possible to switch between application (without going back to the selector application) by linking additional buttons to specific stopApp. I don't know if it's possible to carry information between applications (maybe using session), but I will use a disk file for that.

Let me know if you found a better solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# The tab need to be closed programmatically; here is a quick solution
# https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/close-window/app.R
jscode <- "shinyjs.closeWindow = function() { window.close(); }"


# App One
appOne <- list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("closeWindow")),
    fluidRow(
      column(3),
      mainPanel(h2("Welcome to the load page"),
                plotOutput("plot"),
                actionButton("quit", "QUIT", class = "btn-warning")))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      with(cars, hist(dist, breaks = 10))
    })
    observeEvent(input$quit,  { js$closeWindow(); stopApp("appRoute") })
  }
)

# App TWO
appTwo <- list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("closeWindow")),
    fluidRow(
      column(3),
      mainPanel(h2("Welcome to appTwo"),
                plotOutput("plot"),
                actionButton("quit", "QUIT", class = "btn-warning")))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(cars)
    })
    observeEvent(input$quit,  { js$closeWindow(); stopApp("appRoute") })
  }
)

# Router
appRoute <- list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("closeWindow")),
    fluidRow(
      column(3),
      mainPanel(h2("Welcome to Selector"), 
                actionButton("appOne", "AppOne"), 
                actionButton("appTwo", "AppTwo"), 
                actionButton("appEnd", "END", class = "btn-danger")
      ))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$appOne, { js$closeWindow(); stopApp("appOne") })
    observeEvent(input$appTwo, { js$closeWindow(); stopApp("appTwo") })
    observeEvent(input$appEnd, { js$closeWindow(); stopApp("appEnd") })
  }
)

# Main loop
route <- "appRoute"
while (TRUE) {
  app <- switch(
    route,
    appRoute = shinyApp(appRoute$ui, appRoute$server),
    appOne = shinyApp(appOne$ui, appOne$server),
    appTwo = shinyApp(appTwo$ui, appTwo$server),
    appEnd = "END"
  )
  if (is.null(app)) {  # not matched
    warning("Unknown route ", route)
    route <- "appRoute"
    next
  } else if (is.character(app)) {  # final end
    message("Ending")
    break
  }
  # Execute a new app and retrieve return code
  route <- print(app)
  message("New route ", route)
  # browser()
}
```

Comment: Just found a package (under dev) for multi-page shiny
Multi-page {shiny} Applications with {brochure}
https://colinfay.me/brochure-r-package/

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use `iframe` to do that:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(2,selectInput("Apps", label="Choose an app",choices=c('App1','App2'))),
  column(12, div(style="width: 100%;height: 100%;",htmlOutput("frame")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$frame <- renderUI({
    if(input$Apps == "App1"){
      address <- "https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/genome-browser.html"
    }
    if(input$Apps == "App2"){
      address <- "https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html"
    }
    my_test <- tags$iframe(src=address,height = 1200,width = "100%")
    my_test
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This could help, but I can't run a `shinyApp` inside an iframe if this iframe is in a `shinyApp`

Comment: iframe simply displays apps, as you can see I dont have any code related to those apps in here

Answer (score 0):

I see no way except to run each app into a module. This will be simply done by calling the ui as a function, and the server through `callModule()` (see the numerous articles about modularization). Also, you can re-write each app as a standalone app using a main script calling a single module. Finally, you can switch between the app by numerous ways: using a `selectInput()` combined to a `renderUI()` shall do the work.

Answer (score -2):

By using the reactive function and switch button you can go from one app to other app and no need for two different apps. Just try to write everything in a single App. It will work

Comment: This is a very vague answer. Please go into more detail. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Yeah, they mean 'Thank you so much for contributing to StackOverflow!! Great to have you here. Good for you to know (but no blame whatsoever): your answer could benefit from some more specifics. SO has guidelines [that you can find here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks again for being here!'.